# Pass an object between ViewModels in Silverlight

Tags: c#, mvvm, silverlight-4.0

i have a ViewModel that have a Method to receive  a `Func<Uri,bool>` for navigation and a button that i implement `ICommand` which execute that method(i instantiate ViewModel in Code behind and pass `Navigate` of `Frame` to that).

i navigate between pages properly but there is a no idea to pass an object(e.g Person) to another page because there is **NO** association between `ViewModel`s 
(also i can't use any FrameWork and i don't want to use `QueryString`)

Answer (score 1):

If the answer you found is to use some form of aggregator similar to the Messenger class in [MVVM Light](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/) then I fully endorse it. Don't forget to mark the question as answered if it solved your problem (even if it's your own answer), and maybe even provide some details on what choice you settled on.